# Node.js application to accept JSON from user, manipulate and save to MSSQL

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I'm stuck.  I thought my goal was going to be straight forward but I appear to be missing some key piece.
I'm trying to build a website that can accept a JSON file from an end user.  Once the file has been provided I want to combine that data with data from a web-resource and then take the resulting flattened JSON and write it to a database table.
The first prototype of the project was built in a single HTML page with some JavaScript and I succeeded in getting the output the way I wanted it to look.
Then I tried to convert it to a node.js server so I could use an API to write the resulting JSON to the SQL server.
While the problem with which I am asking for help does not involve those steps I just wanted to share that there are some complexities of async that are possibly muddying things.
I've tried creating an HTML page that accepts a file and using express tried to capture that file, but I can't seem to figure out the right combination of middleware and other code to get the JSON file loaded into an object so I can feed it to my existing function to manipulate it and then subsequently feed it to a function to write it to SQL using a stored procedure.
So here's what I've got for my index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(fileUpload());
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
  }
  let jsonFile = req.body.sampleFile;
  console.log(jsonFile);
  let parsed = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
  console.log
  res.send("blank page");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/minimalIndex.html'));
});
const webserver = app.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log('Express web server is running..');
});
```

and the HTML that it uses is this

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Static Index.html</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form ref='uploadForm' id='uploadForm' action='/upload' method='post' encType="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="sampleFile" />
    <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

The console.log shows undefined.
The JSON Parse fails because of an invalid JSON string.
I've succeeded at saving the file locally but that seems unnecessary.
Can someone please tell me what it is I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is correct apart from the way you are trying to fetch the files. You are trying it from `body` while it should be from `files`. Something like this

```
let jsonFile = req.files.sampleFile;
let parsed = JSON.parse(jsonFile.data.toString("utf-8"));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Ah geez I was afraid it was something simple like that, thank you!